# Should I use Queue<float> to store samples for an audio delay function?

Tags: c#, audio, queue

I'm working on an audio library for the Unity game engine. Currently, I'm reworking a Delay class. It was originally using a float[] to store samples. Here are some of the limitations:

- The class was constructed with the desired delay time and there was no function to resize the array, so:

  - Constructing with 1000 milliseconds of delay would give you an array size of 48000 on Windows machines.
  - You could not change the array size, so no increasing the delay longer than 1000 milliseconds.
  - Decreasing the delay to 0.2 seconds would not remove the unused part of the array and you'd be carrying around data you didn't need anymore.

So I thought the buffer sounded a lot like a Queue. Enqueue a value when you want to write to the buffer. Wait until the queue count reaches your desired delay. Dequeue one off when you want to read. I thought it would be an improvement. And it was. It's much more readable and straightforward and you can easily change the delay time. I imagine it is more RAM efficient as well as the size is only ever as long as it needs to be.

However, it also takes about twice the amount of time to process. We're only talking about 3 or 4 ticks, but in a more complex filter like Reverb which uses several instances of Delay and in an application which could use multiple Reverbs, this could add up.

So my question is: Am I using Queue appropriately? Should I use something else for this? Would it be better to go back to using a simple array and just rewrite it when the delay is changed?

Comment: If you need speed then use plain arrays, collections will alawys be slower than accessing an array.

Comment: Arrays are still the intrinsic container of your samples. Take a look at the implementation of your queue. It will (almost certainly) use arrays for the backing storage. So, should you use an abstraction of arrays? Sure, if it's a good fit for the job. You might, however, find that a (generic) queue implementation leaves a lot to be desired when it comes to using it for DSP purposes.